# Is there any way in flutter where i can set a parameter in one page and display and use it in another page

Tags: flutter, widget

Say i want to set a countdown timer in my project. I want to set timer through slider widget in one page and use it in another page, like if i set 40 seconds timer in one page i want it that when user goes in the next page he is able to see that timer and when the user presses start button it should start running and when pressed stop it should stop?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a own Widget and assign this parameter to this widget. This gives you the possibility to reuse the widget (and the parameter) wherever you want.